# Athena table displaying " in column values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a csv file in s3 with following structure

```
"name1"|"tmc International"|"123, link2"
```

am using below CF template to read this file into Athena

```
T1Table:
       Type: AWS::Glue::Table
       Properties:
         DatabaseName: 'db_1'
         TableInput:
           Name: 'table_1'
           Description: "table_1"
           TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
           Parameters: { "classification" : "csv", "compressionType" : "none", "typeOfData": "file" }
           StorageDescriptor:
             Location: !Sub 's3://temp_loc/temp_csv/'
             InputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
             OutputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
             SerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 serialization.format: '|'
                 field.delim: '|'
                 skip.header.line.count: '1'
                 quoteChar: "\""
                 #input.regex: '\"([^|]*)\"'
               SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
             Columns:
             - {"Name": "name", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "desc1", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "desc2", "Type": "string"}
```

When trying to query this data in Athena the columns are showing the quotes(") in the columns , the fields are separated correctly though. Is there any other format which can render the output without the quotes.

Create table DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_1`(
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `desc1` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `desc2` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'='|', 
  'skip.header.line.count'='1') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://temp_loc/temp_csv/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'typeOfData'='file')
```

Comment: I see that you are using quoteChar but the serde should be  org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde for it to work

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy - if I use that then output has only one column rendered like this - "name1"|"tmc International"|"123, link2"

Comment: replace all other SerdeInfo parameters with separatorChar = "|", quoteChar = "\"" and SerializationLibrary as org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde which definitely will work

Comment: so this is what my parameters look like @PrabhakarReddy post incorporating your suggestionsSerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 #serialization.format: '|'
                 #field.delim: '|'
                 separatorChar: '|'
                 skip.header.line.count: '1'
                 quoteChar: "\""
                 #input.regex: '\"([^|]*)\"'
               SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'  , but this does not resolve the issue now athena ouput renders a single column only.

Comment: use just these SerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 separatorChar = "|",
                 quoteChar = "\"" 
SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

Comment: yes this is exactly what I have used. but it does not work @PrabhakarReddy ,SerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 separatorChar: '|'
                 quoteChar: "\""
               SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

Comment: Can you run show create table <table-name> in athena and post your query output here?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy - I have added create DDL to the  original question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222367/discussion-between-prabhakar-reddy-and-sl).

Answer (score 1):

The default CSV serde (serializer/deserializer) in Athena does not support quoted fields. You need to use the alternative serde: [OpenCSVSerDe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html).

This serde has different names for the configuration parameters. Instead of `field.delim` you use `separatorChar`. The quote character is configured by `quoteChar`, which you already have in your template (it's just not working with the serde you are using).

Your configuration should look something like this:

```yaml
…
SerdeInfo:
  Parameters:
    separatorChar: '|'
    quoteChar: '"'
    'skip.header.line.count': '1'
  SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
…
```

Comment: I have tried the exact SerdeInfo but the quotes still persist. Could it be due to the encoding of the file, the file is UTF-16 LE encoded.

Comment: Possibly, but that should be solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64166953/athena-displays-special-characters-as/64207183#64207183 – right?

Comment: you mean , adding  'encoding' :' UTF-16' to SerdeInfo ?

Comment: yes, if you did that the encoding should not be a problem anymore, and this issue should not be because of encoding problems

Comment: Still getting the quotes issues , below is how my SerdeInfo looks like                                             Parameters:
                 separatorChar: '|'
                 quoteChar: '"'
                 skip.header.line.count: '1'
                 encoding: 'UTF-16' 
               SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'

Answer (score 1):

If your table has partitions, please verify the partition properties for SerDe info. It may still be showing serialization lib 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' . If so, you will have to use partition API and change it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below CF template to create table by looking at your data assuming there is no header in the source file and was able to query it fine.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Glue Table
Resources:
  T1Table:
       Type: AWS::Glue::Table
       Properties:
         DatabaseName: 'db_1'
         CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId

         TableInput:
           Name: 'table_1'
           Description: "table_1"
           TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
           
           StorageDescriptor:
             Location: !Sub 's3://s3path/'
             InputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
             OutputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
             SerdeInfo:
               Parameters:
                 quoteChar: "\""
                 separatorChar: "|"
               SerializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
             Columns:
             - {"Name": "name", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "desc1", "Type": "string"}
             - {"Name": "desc2", "Type": "string"}
```

This created a table with below definition :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `table_1`(
  `name` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `desc1` string COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `desc2` string COMMENT 'from deserializer')
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'quoteChar'='\"', 
  'separatorChar'='|') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://s3path/'
```

Then I ran a select query which gave me expected output as shown below:

[image]